# php curl returns 400 Bad Request if does in a loop

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do a screen scrape using the cUrl library.

I managed to successfully screen scrape, few urls(5-10).

However whenever i run it in a for loop scraping a bulk(10-20) urls,

it will reach a point the last few urls will returns  "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". 
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
The number of request header fields exceeds this server's limit.

I'm pretty sure the urls are correct and correctly trimmed and the headers length are the same individually. If i put these last few urls on top of the list to scrape, it does go through, but the last few of the list again gets the 400 Bad request error. What could be the problem? What could be the cause?

Any advise ?

Something like below:

```
for($i=0;$i > sizeof($url);$i++)    
$data[$i] = $this->get($url[$i]); 



function get($url) {

$this->headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
        $this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
        $this->headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
        $this->user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)';

set_time_limit(EXECUTION_TIME_LIMIT);
        $default_exec_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');

        $this->redirectcount = 0;
        $process = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
        if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
        if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);

        //off compression for debugging's sake
        //curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression);

        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
        if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy);
        if ($this->proxyauth){ 
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1); 
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $this->proxyauth);  
         }
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10); 

        //added
        //curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,TRUE);
        if ($this->referrer) curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_REFERER,$this->referrer);

        if($this->cookies){
            foreach($this->cookies as $cookie){
                curl_setopt ($process, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
                //echo $cookie; 
            }
        }

        $return = $this->redirect_exec($process);//curl_exec($process) or curl_error($process);
        curl_close($process);
        set_time_limit($default_exec_time);//setback to default

        return $return;
    }

    function redirect_exec($ch, $curlopt_header = false) {

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $file = fopen(DP_SCRAPE_DATA_CURL_DIR.$this->redirectcount.".html","w");
    fwrite($file,$data);
    fclose($file);

    $info =    curl_getinfo($ch);
    print_r($info);echo "
";

    $http_code = $info['http_code'];
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302 || $http_code == 303) {
        //list($header) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data);
        //print_r($header);
        $matches = array();
        //print_r($data);

        //Check if the response has a Location to redirect to
        preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/', $data, $matches);
        $url = trim(array_pop($matches));
        //print_r($url);
        $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
        //print_r($url_parsed);
        if (isset($url_parsed['path']) && isset($url) && !empty($url) ) {
            //echo "
".$url;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, MY_HOST.$url);
            //echo "
".$url;
            $this->redirectcount++;
            return $this->redirect_exec($ch);
            //return $this->get(MY_HOST.$url); //$this->redirect_exec($ch);
        }
    }

    elseif($http_code == 200){
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/(/i', $data, $matches);
        //print_r($matches);
        $url = trim(array_pop($matches));
        //print_r($url);
        $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
        //print_r($url_parsed);
        if (isset($url_parsed['path']) && isset($url) && !empty($url) ) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            //echo "
".$url;
            $this->redirectcount++;
            sleep(SLEEP_INTERVAL);
            return $this->redirect_exec($ch);
            //return $this->get($url); //$this->redirect_exec($ch);
        }
    }
    //echo "data ".$data;
    $this->redirectcount++;

    return  $data ; // $info['url'];
    }
```

where $urls are all the urls containing all query string for a get request

i realised from curl_getinfo , the  [request_size ] is getting larger and larger which it shouldnt be.. it should be about the same size. How can i print/echo my http request information to debug?

Comment: Please show us your code. I suspect you keep piling on parameters instead if resetting them for each iteration.

Comment: we can't tell the time without a clock, but you're saying the clock is broken. show us the clock.

Comment: basically, i'm doing a for loop on curl_exec on a $url using GET. $url[0] .. $url[99] is of the same length, not piling on the parameters . however like from the $url[90] on wards, i keep hitting 400 bad request error.

Comment: i realised from curl_getinfo , the [request_size ] is getting larger and larger after each iteration which it shouldnt be.. it should be about the same size. How can i print/echo my http request information to debug?

Comment: suspecting the request size is increasing for every loop hence getting larger and larger, how do i overcome this? will CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT solve the problem or closing and reopening exec connection help? What's the best way to overcome this? anyone? also how can i print out the requests http ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem regarding the multiplying headers is at the top of the `get` method:

```
$this->headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
$this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
$this->headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
```

On each iteration you are adding the same headers to the `headers` array of the object instance. (Saying `array[]` appends to the array.) You need to either reset the array on each iteration or perhaps move the headers setting into another method.

If `headers` is always and only set in the `get` method, you can change it to this in order to fix the problem:

```
$this->headers = array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
);
```

...but if the headers are always the same and never changed between iterations, you might as well set the headers' value in the object constructor and only read from it in the `get` method, since resetting the array to the same value all the time is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` to true, I am able to retrieve the request information sent.

Indeed, the request headers gets more and more information

I particularly has this header incrementing!

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Anyone knows what is happening? how come the headers for accept and content-type gets added on each time it runs thru a iteration????

Comment: You should update your question if you're adding more information to it, not create an answer. Not everyone views the answers ordered by time. (AFAIK the default ordering is by votes.)